# How do I make the title 'Figure' appear on the same page as my first figure

Tags: sectioning, floats, page-breaking

This is my code:

```
    \documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
    \title{}
    \author{}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    %\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{listings}
    %\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{cases}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
    %\usepackage{mathpazo}
    %\usepackage{eulervm}
    %\usepackage{iwona}
    \usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

    \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

    \linespread{1.5}

    \usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

    \raggedbottom

    \everymath{\displaystyle} 

    \newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

    \begin{document}


    \newpage
\section{Figures}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{Bootstrapped Probability of Default for Sovereigns} \\ This graph plots the bootstrapped probabilities of default ($PoD$) of 10 Euro Area (EA) sovereigns. The country abbreviations are shown in Table~\ref{tab:sovereignabbreviation}. All reported $PoD$s are annualized 5-year cumulative CDS-derived $PoD$s. All CDS contracts, except for Spain (SPA), are dollar (USD) denominated. We use euro denominated CDS contracts for Spain. Period: 01/01/2008 to 28/02/2013.}
  \label{bootstrapsovereign}

\includegraphics[scale=0.70]{podsovereign.png}

\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

However, the result is that I do not have the title `Figures' on the same starting page as my first figure:

### Blank title page

[image: blank]

### First figure

[image: first figure]

How can I make the section title `Figure' appear above my first figure?

Comment: `landscape` always makes a new page. You're probably interested in the `sidewaysfigure` of the `rotating` package. Of course you must ensure that the figure fits in the page containing the section title.

Comment: I tried using sidewaysfigure however all it does is rotate the figure the other way, I am unsure as to how I can use it to combine the title and figure.

Comment: It may not be acceptable but would you mind having the section title on the landscape page also? Then it would just be a case of moving `\section{figures}` into the `landscape` environment, after some scaling you could have a landscape title and figure page.

Comment: if you use the rotating package, read section 2.1 about package options: the "clockwise" and "anticlockwise" provide control over the rotation direction.  however, rotated figures (`sidewaysfigure` environment) are *always* full-page floats, so not really for you.  the `turn` environment may prove a route to what you want, but it won't help in the example you give, since there doesn't seem to be space on the page for the section title and the figure.  (note: when i retire, i'll try to make the doc of the `rotating` package more readable.)

Comment: It's tricky for us reproduce your exact problem without access to your `podsovereign.png` image. Could you either upload it, or tell us its dimensions?

Comment: A minor comment: you loaded the `listings` package twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

[image]

What I did:

- Passed the `demo` option to the `article` class, which shows a big black box instead of your png image (which I don't have access to).
- Used the `[h]` option for the `figure`, so that the figure wouldn't be moved to its own page.
- Adjusted `\textfraction` to `0.1`, to stop large figures hijacking the entire page. This way, it is allowable for text to take up only 10% of a page.
- Rotated the caption (using `\rotcaption` from the `rotating` package).
- Rotated the image (using `\rotatebox` from the `rotating` package).
- Used two `minipage`s, one for the caption and one for the image, so they can be placed side-by-side.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt,demo]{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}


% don't let large figures hijack entire pages
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}

\begin{document}


\newpage
\section{Figures}


\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup{width=200mm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{27mm}
\rotcaption{\textbf{Bootstrapped Probability of Default for Sovereigns} \\ This graph plots the bootstrapped probabilities of default ($PoD$) of 10 Euro Area (EA) sovereigns. The country abbreviations are shown in Table~\ref{tab:sovereignabbreviation}. All reported $PoD$s are annualized 5-year cumulative CDS-derived $PoD$s. All CDS contracts, except for Spain (SPA), are dollar (USD) denominated. We use euro denominated CDS contracts for Spain. Period: 01/01/2008 to 28/02/2013.}
\label{bootstrapsovereign}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{125mm}
\rotatebox{270}{\includegraphics[scale=0.70,width=210mm,height=125mm]{podsovereign.png}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.